# Discord.py Get connected voice clients after reconnection

Tags: discord.py

I have a cog that does some audio stuff.  It stores the voice state in `self.voice` whenever the voice state updates (and limits actually updating it to when `member` is the bot.

But when the bot stops and reruns (like killing the python process), it stays connected to the voice channel for several minutes before timing out and disconnecting.  I can't disconnect it manually because `self.voice` is just None initially.

Is there a way to get the current voice state when the bot is run again, so I can set `self.voice`?  Alternatively, is there a way to immediately force disconnect the bot from any voice channels it's still in after restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an [event listener](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener) in your cog for [on_disconnect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_disconnect#discord.on_disconnect), wherein you disconnect your bot from all voice channels.  As long as you stop your bot gracefully it should fire this event listener.